# Why did two of the development Concordes have red cabin doors?

Tags: aviation-history, concorde

[image: Concorde in flight]
The second British Concorde 101 G-AXDN at the 1974 Farnborough Airshow
(Photo by: Richard Vandervord source: [www.airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/) via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Second_British_Concorde_sweeps_gracefully_past_the_crowd_at_the_1974_SBAC_show.jpg), CC BY-SA 4.0)

Three of the six development Concordes were built by the French, #1, #4, and #5. Three were built by the British, #2, #3, and #6. The #2 and #3 British planes were Concorde 002 G-BSST, and Concorde 101 G-AXDN which is famous for being the fastest Concorde ever flown. These were the first two British Concordes ever built.

The middle cabin doors on each side of G-BSST and G-AXDN were both painted red, the same color as the stripe that runs the length of the planes. This is easily seen in any color photos of these two planes. As far as I can tell these are the only two Concordes that ever had red cabin doors.

One possibility is that this was some type of an indicator to fire rescue personnel. But if so why only these two doors, and why only these two planes? And is it just a coincidence that both of the planes with red doors were British built? Was it just an aesthetic to make these two early test planes easily identifiable?

Another possible clue is that all three of the British development planes have another distinguishing feature that the three French development planes do not have, which is some black squares in various parts of the planes, for example near the nose of G-AXDN. My guess is that these black squares are for photographic tracking, similar to the black stripes and blocks on the Saturn V rocket which were used to measure the roll rate during launch. Perhaps the red doors on G-BSST and G-AXDN served a similar purpose in test photography, although the fact that they are red seems to make this possibility less likely.

Comment: There are [many particularities listed in this document](https://faq-fra.aviatechno.net/guide/concorde.php) in French, o/w the red doors and the tracking marks, the exhaust eyelids, opaque nose, etc, found on prototypes and development/test versions by c/n or tail number.

Comment: @mins - The document mentions the red doors on G-AXDN but no explanation is given, “On many photos the emergency doors located in the center of the fuselage are red on a white background”. This remark implies that G-AXDN did not always have red doors, but the only photos that I have found of it without red doors were photos taken at or shortly after rollout. And I have not found any photos of G-BSST without red doors. The document also mentions the black squares, “bears telemetry aid markings on the front, a kind of checkerboard with 2 black tiles”. Presumably this refers to ground tracking.

Comment: The mark seems to be for take-off/landing performance evaluation by a [camera on the ground](http://www.concordesst.com/history/testing69/002firsttouchdown.jpg) (on the left side only).

Comment: @mins - That could be although that photo of G-BSST was taken on its maiden flight in 1969 before the black squares (and red doors) were added. The checkerboard markings are quite visible in photos of the three British development planes. The black squares on G-AXDN are on both sides of the nose and seem to be oriented towards the ground so I suspect they were for inflight ground tracking. G-BSST has black squares over the right wing not visible to ground cameras so maybe used for takeoff and landing tracking. But G-BSST also had squares under the nose. G-BDDG has squares over the left wing.

Comment: [G-AXDN nose](http://www.jetphotos.com/photo/5619552) [G-BSST wing](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8700036) [G-BSST under nose](https://www.airliners.net/photo/British-Aircraft-Corporation-Sud-Aviation-France/Sud-BAC-Concorde/1221210) [G-BDDG wing](http://www.concordesst.com/pictures/gbbdg4.jpg)

Comment: @mins I've zoomed in to 260% on that image and I'm not sure which marks you're talking about. I only see the faintest of a "U" shaped line just ahead of the stripe - this looks like it could be the main cabin door, but I'm not sure. Is this what you're talking about? If not, could you please identify what particular mark you're referring to.

Comment: @FreeMan: If you're talking about [this image](http://www.concordesst.com/history/testing69/002firsttouchdown.jpg), then there is no mark. I was referring to [the mark in the question](http://www.concordesst.com/pictures/gaxdn6.jpg). But the image I posted shows the cine-theodolite used to track aircraft.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the touch down image. I see from "the mark in the question" that what I saw in touch down is the outline of the door. I presume the cine-theodolite is the checkerboard pattern, but I'm not seeing that in touch down. (Unless it's the black mark on the belly, just behind the main cabin door, which I just noticed.)

Comment: @FreeMan: My assumption is the cine-theodolite (ground camera) tracked the checkerboard pattern to determine the motion of the plane. Unfortunately I've not enough details, I don't know if this was used by the English or the French engineers, or both. Possibly only the BAC (UK) planes had a checkerboard (I've not checked).

Comment: @mins – I agree the checkerboards were likely for measuring motion. Similar patterns were used on rockets to measure roll rates and other attitude changes. The checkerboards over the wings were probably not used for landing but for aerial filming, for the same purpose to measure roll rate and attitude changes. Aerial photography might seem unstable but probably no more than ground based cinetheodolite tracking cameras which although of course very steady, they were manually operated back then, and shooting from far away. Airborne had the advantage of being close for more precise measurements.

Comment: Some additional evidence about the red doors. Close up photos of G-BSST reveal that it had four additional “exits” on each side with a marked outline and the words “Cut Here In Emergency” below them. Clearly intended for fire rescue personnel. Interestingly two of the eight cutouts are located immediately adjacent to the red emergency exits. On the right side of G-BSST the red overwing exit appears to be the only functioning exit door on that side. On the left side there is the main cabin door along with the red overwing exit and four cutouts. And there was an emergency exit hatch in the tail.

Comment: However any red door theories based on the G-BSST door situation don’t quite hold up when looking at the next development plane G-AXDN. It has similar cutout outlines but without the “Cut Here In Emergency” message. The red overwing exit doors on G-AXDN are nearly full size doors, whereas G-BSST had small overwing exits. G-AXDN also had a functioning cabin door on the right rear. And it had an additional non-red emergency exit over the right wing, and two non-red emergency exits on the left side. So it’s still not quite clear why one emergency exit on each side of the plane is painted red.

Comment: [G-BSST Cut Here In Emergency](https://www.airliners.net/photo/British-Aircraft-Corporation-Sud-Aviation-France/Sud-BAC-Concorde/2629389) [G-BSST cutout next to small red door](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8700036) [G-BSST right front door inoperable](https://www.airliners.net/photo/British-Aircraft-Corporation-Aerospatiale-France/Sud-BAC-Concorde/696516) [G-AXDN left side doors](http://www.concordesst.com/pictures/gaxdn4.jpg)

Comment: I have no additional clue. Two elements to consider: These aircraft had no commercial passengers, exits were for engineers. Most of the test flights were likely conducted over water, overwing exits are the one used.

Comment: @mins – The emergency exits on test flights would have been used in a crash landing, fire, runway excursion, or if it survived water impact. My guess is they would have used the wing exits so they could drop down from the wingtips which were lower to the ground, or on F-WTSS and G-BSST from the hatch in the tail, but it's unclear if those had stairs. Production Concordes had escape slides and rafts. The first four test planes had escape hatches at the front and mid section allowing the pilots and test engineers to bail out even at supersonic speeds after donning pressure suits and parachutes.

Comment: After examining the exits on the two planes I have come up with a theory. Possibly the red doors are the only emergency exits that can be opened from the outside. I can see some markings on the red doors that could indicate some type of handle or release, whereas I don't see anything similar on the other emergency exits. Of course the main cabin door could be opened from the outside, but that would already be obvious to rescue personnel. To help confirm this theory it would help to find some close up photos of the exit doors on these two planes, but so far I have not been able to locate any.